# Understanding binary files

Tags: windows, hex, binary-data

I wrote "blue thief" in a `.txt` file:

[image]

How the information is stored in hex format? How the text was converted into those characters? I heard binary files contain header, ftm and the data. Is that only with multimedia files like audio and video? Because I don't see anything other than the `data` in this file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The characters in your text file are encoded in [a Windows extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) of [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)--one byte for each character that you see in Notepad.  What you see is what you get.

Generally, a hard distinction is made between text and binary files on Windows systems.  On Unix/Linux systems, the distinction is fuzzier... you could argue that there is no distinction, in fact.

On Windows systems, the distinction is enforced by file extensions.  All files with the extension ".TXT" are assumed to be text files (i.e., to contain only hex codes that represent visible onscreen characters, where "visible" includes whitespace).

Binary files are a whole different kettle of fish.  Most, as you mention, include some sort of header describing how the data that follows is encoded.  These headers can vary tremendously in size depending on the type of data (again, assumed to be indicated by the extension on Windows systems as well as Unix).  A simple example is the [WAV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) for uncompressed audio.  If you open a WAV file in your hex editing program, you'll see that the first four bytes are "RIFF"--this is a marker, often called a "magic number" even though it is readable as text, indicating that the contents are an audio file.  Newer versions of the WAV specification have complicated this somewhat, but originally the WAV header was just the "RIFF" tag plus a dozen or so bytes indicating the sample rate of the following data.  (You can see this by comparing the raw data in a track on an audio CD to the WAV file created by ripping an uncompressed copy of that track at 44.1 KHz--the data should be the same, with just a header section added at the start of the WAV file.)

Executable files (compiled programs) are a special type of binary file, but they follow roughly the same scheme of a header followed by data in a prescribed format.  In this case, though, the "data" is executable machine code, and the header indicates, among other things, what operating system the file runs on.   (For example, most Linux executables [begin with the characters "ELF"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).)

Comment: Impressive. You just more or less, described what I wanted to know. One final question though. How can I learn more about this? Which link would you recommend that could be helpful to me to understand about this?

Comment: @bluethief Depends what direction you want to go.  For more about file extensions and different ways of encoding data, [this Wikipedia list of file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats) looks like a good start.  For more about character encodings in text files, first follow the link above for ASCII, then read about [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).  If you are interested in how these representations work at a hardware level, you might read about [binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code) and [disk drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_storage).